# Can a psionic at-will from Half-Elf Polymath be augmented?

Tags: dnd-4e

At-wills you get from racial traits can't be augmented. So a Half-Elf's dilettante power can't be augmented, even if it's psionic.

But a half-elf who takes the Half-Elf Polymath Paragon Path (Dragon magazine #385, pg.69) gets to pick up an at-will as one of the Paragon Path's features -- not as a racial trait.

If that at-will has augmentations, are they usable?

Answer (score 2):

### *TL;DR:* Paragon Paths aren't racial traits so you can use the augmentations but only if you have access to Power Points.

Paragon Paths are a separate feature from racial traits and even class features, as stated on page 53 of the Player's Handbook:

> **Path Features:** Every paragon path grants you *specific path features,* which are similar in nature to the features you gain from your class.

Given that racial paragon paths weren't introduced until the second Player's Handbook, I think it stands to reason that this also applies to them.
Therefore you aren't restricted by the "racial traits can't be augmented" rule.

**However, there is another (potential) problem.**

From page 115 of the Rules Compendium:

> A power that has the augmentable keyword has optional augmentations, which a character can use **at the cost of power points.** Only certain characters have power points, usually as a result of their class. [...]
>
> > [...] The creature must spend the required power points when it decides to use the augmentation

So unless you are already a psionic class or you multiclass into one you wouldn't be unable to use the augmentations because you don't have the power points to spend on them.